Integrate takes long time
This Integration does not return for hours, though I don't know why as the graph doesn't look all that complicated.  Also NIntegrate returns the result instantly... but I need the exact value!
Integrate[1/((1 + x^2015) (1 + x^2)), {x, 0, Infinity}]

Is there any way to simplify it or tell Mathematica to use a more efficient memory map, etc.?

$\frac{\pi }{4}$

Thanks, but how? ...

Try to replace 2015 with some small number and then some other small number...

Yes it's always Pi/4, however it's not a proof for the original question

But if your original Integrate returned $\pi/4$, would you consider that a proof?

Naturally - is there a way to solve the original one

The graphs or all other powers look different, so I am sure there is a mathematical way of proving the area is preserved, independent of the exponent.

Not complicated? There are 2,017 poles....1,009 real factors...It may not be complicated, but it's quite a large computation. For instance, this quits after 4 sec: MemoryConstrained[Integrate[1/((1 + x^2015)  (1 + x^2)), {x, 0, 1, Infinity}], 10^7]

Gocha, Thx! So mathematica barfs after 10^7 bytes of mem usage normally? ....

fyi, I tried this on few other CAS systems (Maple, Fricas, Rubi, Mupad) and none of them can do it.

int = RootApproximant[NIntegrate[1/((1 + x^2015)  (1 + x^2)), {x, 0, Infinity}] / Pi] * Pi evaluates to Pi/4

@Bill Watts: I tried that (with a) but it just spits out the same input for me with the Integral sign! lol

With v14, I got a solution for the indefinite integral.

oh mine's 12.1.1.0 -- didn't realize that makes a difference! (They have improved it that much? wow)  However I tried with different x^a powers, like 2,3, 4,5,6 ...and each yields a different looking result!  Try it!

I think you are right about the integral, because I can't reproduce my results from yesterday.  I may have had the value a assigned without realizing it.

Using change of variables $x\rightarrow\frac{1}{u}$ simplifies matters. Summing the two equivalent integrals allows one to integrate $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx=\pi/2$ Therefore, the desired integral is $\pi/4$.
i1 = ExpandDenominator[1/((1 + x^2015) (1 + x^2))]
i2 = -(i1 /. x -> 1/u) D[1/u, u] (* note the negative sign takes   care of swapping of bounds of integration*)
i3 = (ExpandDenominator[i2] u^2015 // Simplify)/u^2015
i4 = Together[i1 + i3 /. x -> u]

Putting all together:
Row[{HoldForm[
    Integrate[1/((1 + x^2015) (1 + x^2)), {x, 0, Infinity}]], " = ", 
   int}] /. 
 Solve[2 int == Integrate[i4, {u, 0 , Infinity}], int ][[1]]


Of course, this is just using Mathematica/Wolfram Language as "a typewriter" (as some people like to criticize). I post it to confirm the result.

Nice one @ubpdqn   -- wow brilliant substitution!

@Steve237 simplifies things. Thought of it while driving home from work: probably just remembering what someone taught me rather than original. Useful tricks

Workaround, using Mellin Transform(Inverse Mellin):
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{1}{\left(1+x^2\right) \left(1+x^m\right)} \, dx=\text{FoxH(m)}$$
InverseMellinTransform[Integrate[
MellinTransform[1/((1 + x^2) (1 + A*x^m)), A, s], {x, 0, Infinity},
Assumptions -> m > 0], s, A] /. A -> 1(*Can't compute!!!*)

(*1/2 \[Pi]^2 InverseMellinTransform[Csc[\[Pi] s] Sec[(m \[Pi] s)/2], s,
A, Assumptions -> -1 < m Re[s] < 1]*)

If we convert from trig to gamma:
$$\frac{1}{2} \pi ^2 \csc (\pi  s) \sec \left(\frac{m \pi  s}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \Gamma (1-s) \Gamma (s) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m s}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{m s}{2}\right)$$
and using defintion of FoxH function we have general solution:
1/2 FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, 1]// TeXForm
(*Converting to LATEX expression contains errors. This Bug exist 
 from version MMA 12.3.I reported ,but WRI ignores this matter.*)

.
Table[1/2 FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, 1] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify, {m, 0, 10}]

 (*{\[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, \[Pi]/4, 1/2 FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {1/2, 9/2}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}, {1/2, 9/2}}, {}}, 1], \[Pi]/4}*)
 (*Can't compute for m = 9 *)

N[1/2 FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, 1] /. m -> 2015]
(*Can't compute!!!*)

1/2 FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}, {1/2, m/2}}, {}}, 
x] /. m -> 2015 /. x -> 0.9

(*I aborted with 1 hour computation with no answer! *)

UPDATE: 29.12.2024
Using this: Evaluation of Definite Integrals via the Residue Theorem. ECE 6382. Notes are from D. R. Wilton, Dept. of ECE. 1. David R. Jackson. Fall 2023. Notes 11 and using example on page 11, in short we have:
Z = 1/2*(2 Pi I*ResidueSum[{1/((1 + z^2)*(1 + z^2015)), Im[z] >= 0}, z] - 
 Integrate[Limit[(I E^(I \[Theta]) \[Rho])/((1 + (-1 + 
       E^(I \[Theta]) \[Rho])^2) (1 + (-1 + 
       E^(I \[Theta]) \[Rho])^2015)), \[Rho] -> 0, 
  Assumptions -> \[Theta] > 0], {\[Theta], Pi, 2 Pi}] - 
Integrate[Limit[(I E^(I \[Phi])*R)/((1 + E^(2 I \[Phi]) R^2) (1 + E^(2015 I \[Phi])*R^2015)), 
  R -> Infinity], {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}]);

N[Z - Pi/4, 100] // Quiet

(*0.*10^-149 + 0.*10^-149 I*)

FullSimplify[Z] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.0000673 -> :P, \[Pi]/4}*)


FindSequenceFunction[ParallelTable[Integrate[1/((1 + x^n) (1 + x^2)), {x, 0, Infinity}], {n, 1,12}], n]//Timing


{0.921875, \[Pi]/4}


(–1) Not rigorous at all. See for example Borwein integral.

@Domen: Integrate[1/(1 + x^70)/(1 + x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] // Timing results in {37.7656, \[Pi]/2}.
